# Time out while connecting to Orderer node of HyperLedger using java sdk based client

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to invoke existing example of Hyperledger fabcar using Java client (making use of java sdk integration). I have setup fabric on one of my AWS instances and am running everything as is. However, when I am executing my program and it reaches to `Channel.initialize()` it throws following exception

> Sep 12, 2017 8:57:08 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel
>   getConfigurationBlock SEVERE: Channel mychannel sendDeliver time
>   exceeded for orderer orderer.example.com, timed out at 3000
>   org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: Channel
>   mychannel sendDeliver time exceeded for orderer orderer.example.com,
>   timed out at 3000
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.OrdererClient.sendDeliver(OrdererClient.java:282)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Orderer.sendDeliver(Orderer.java:172)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.seekBlock(Channel.java:1220)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getLatestBlock(Channel.java:1296)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getLastConfigIndex(Channel.java:1119)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getConfigurationBlock(Channel.java:1046)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.parseConfigBlock(Channel.java:967)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.initialize(Channel.java:694)
>           at Client.main(Client.java:73)
>
> Sep 12, 2017 8:57:08 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel
>   parseConfigBlock SEVERE: Channel mychannel sendDeliver time exceeded
>   for orderer orderer.example.com, timed out at 3000
>   org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: Channel
>   mychannel sendDeliver time exceeded for orderer orderer.example.com,
>   timed out at 3000
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.OrdererClient.sendDeliver(OrdererClient.java:282)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Orderer.sendDeliver(Orderer.java:172)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.seekBlock(Channel.java:1220)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getLatestBlock(Channel.java:1296)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getLastConfigIndex(Channel.java:1119)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getConfigurationBlock(Channel.java:1046)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.parseConfigBlock(Channel.java:967)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.initialize(Channel.java:694)
>           at Client.main(Client.java:73)
>
> Sep 12, 2017 8:57:08 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel initialize
>   SEVERE: Channel mychannel sendDeliver time exceeded for orderer
>   orderer.example.com, timed out at 3000
>   org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: Channel
>   mychannel sendDeliver time exceeded for orderer orderer.example.com,
>   timed out at 3000
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.OrdererClient.sendDeliver(OrdererClient.java:282)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Orderer.sendDeliver(Orderer.java:172)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.seekBlock(Channel.java:1220)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getLatestBlock(Channel.java:1296)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getLastConfigIndex(Channel.java:1119)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getConfigurationBlock(Channel.java:1046)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.parseConfigBlock(Channel.java:967)
>           at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.initialize(Channel.java:694)
>           at Client.main(Client.java:73)

EDIT 1: The same issue running on Ubuntu 16.04. On `channel.initialize();` I get:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: Channel
>   mychannel sendDeliver time exceeded for orderer orderer, timed out at
>   3000  at
>   org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.OrdererClient.sendDeliver(OrdererClient.java:282)
>     at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Orderer.sendDeliver(Orderer.java:172)
>     at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.seekBlock(Channel.java:1198)
>     at
>   org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getLatestBlock(Channel.java:1274)
>     at
>   org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getLastConfigIndex(Channel.java:1097)
>     at
>   org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getConfigurationBlock(Channel.java:1028)
>     at
>   org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.parseConfigBlock(Channel.java:949)
>     at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.initialize(Channel.java:676)
>     at com.test.test.Program.main(Program.java:65)

Here is the sample code:

```
package com.test.test;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.ChaincodeID;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Enrollment;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.HFClient;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.ProposalResponse;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.QueryByChaincodeRequest;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.TransactionProposalRequest;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.User;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.security.CryptoSuite;

public class Program {

    private static HFClient client = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        /*
         * wallet_path: path.join(__dirname, './creds'), user_id: 'PeerAdmin',
         * channel_id: 'mychannel', chaincode_id: 'fabcar', network_url:
         * 'grpc://192.168.99.100:7051', orderer: grpc://192.168.99.100:7050
         * 
         */

        // just new objects, without any payload inside
        client = HFClient.createNewInstance();
        CryptoSuite cs = CryptoSuite.Factory.getCryptoSuite();
        client.setCryptoSuite(cs);

        // We implement User interface below in code
        // folder c:\tmp\creds should contain PeerAdmin.cert (extracted from HF's fabcar
        // example's PeerAdmin json file)
        // and PeerAdmin.priv (copy from
        // cd96d5260ad4757551ed4a5a991e62130f8008a0bf996e4e4b84cd097a747fec-priv)
        User user = new SampleUser("/home/brankoterzic/Desktop/HyperledgerFabric/fabric-samples/fabric-samples/fabcar/creds", "PeerAdmin");
        // "Log in"
        client.setUserContext(user);

        // Instantiate channel
        Channel channel = client.newChannel("mychannel");
        channel.addPeer(client.newPeer("peer", "grpc://192.168.99.100:7051"));
        // It always wants orderer, otherwise even query does not work
        channel.addOrderer(client.newOrderer("orderer", "grpc://192.168.99.100:7050"));
        channel.initialize();

        // below is querying and setting new owner

        String newOwner = "New Owner #" + new Random(new Date().getTime()).nextInt(999);
        System.out.println("New owner is '" + newOwner + "'\n");

        queryFabcar(channel, "CAR1");
        updateCarOwner(channel, "CAR1", newOwner, false);

        System.out.println("after request for transaction without commit");
        queryFabcar(channel, "CAR1");
        updateCarOwner(channel, "CAR1", newOwner, true);

        System.out.println("after request for transaction WITH commit");
        queryFabcar(channel, "CAR1");

        System.out.println("Sleeping 5s");
        Thread.sleep(5000); // 5secs
        queryFabcar(channel, "CAR1");
        System.out.println("all done");
    }

    private static void queryFabcar(Channel channel, String key) throws Exception {
        QueryByChaincodeRequest req = client.newQueryProposalRequest();
        ChaincodeID cid = ChaincodeID.newBuilder().setName("fabcar").build();
        req.setChaincodeID(cid);
        req.setFcn("queryCar");
        req.setArgs(new String[] { key });
        System.out.println("Querying for " + key);
        Collection<ProposalResponse> resps = channel.queryByChaincode(req);
        for (ProposalResponse resp : resps) {
            String payload = new String(resp.getChaincodeActionResponsePayload());
            System.out.println("response: " + payload);
        }

    }

    private static void updateCarOwner(Channel channel, String key, String newOwner, Boolean doCommit)
            throws Exception {
        TransactionProposalRequest req = client.newTransactionProposalRequest();
        ChaincodeID cid = ChaincodeID.newBuilder().setName("fabcar").build();
        req.setChaincodeID(cid);
        req.setFcn("changeCarOwner");
        req.setArgs(new String[] { key, newOwner });
        System.out.println("Executing for " + key);
        Collection<ProposalResponse> resps = channel.sendTransactionProposal(req);
        if (doCommit) {
            channel.sendTransaction(resps);
        }
    }

}

/***
 * Implementation of user. main business logic (as for fabcar example) is in
 * getEnrollment - get user's private key and cert
 * 
 */
class SampleUser implements User {
    private final String certFolder;
    private final String userName;

    public SampleUser(String certFolder, String userName) {
        this.certFolder = certFolder;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getRoles() {
        return new HashSet<String>();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAccount() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getAffiliation() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public Enrollment getEnrollment() {
        return new Enrollment() {

            @Override
            public PrivateKey getKey() {
                try {
                    return loadPrivateKey(Paths.get(certFolder, userName + ".priv"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String getCert() {
                try {
                    return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(certFolder, userName + ".cert")));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return "";
                }
            }

        };
    }

    @Override
    public String getMspId() {
        return "Org1MSP";
    }
    /***
     * loading private key from .pem-formatted file, ECDSA algorithm
     * (from some example on StackOverflow, slightly changed)
     * @param fileName - file with the key
     * @return Private Key usable
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException
     */
    public static PrivateKey loadPrivateKey(Path fileName) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        PrivateKey key = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(fileName.toString());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            boolean inKey = false;
            for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
                if (!inKey) {
                    if (line.startsWith("-----BEGIN ") && line.endsWith(" PRIVATE KEY-----")) {
                        inKey = true;
                    }
                    continue;
                } else {
                    if (line.startsWith("-----END ") && line.endsWith(" PRIVATE KEY-----")) {
                        inKey = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            }
            //
            byte[] encoded = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(builder.toString());
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA");
            key = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        return key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the port value for ordering service endpoint? E.g. orderer.example.com:7050?

Comment: @ArtemBarger  while creating an orderer, I am giving the port number ..like this.. but still not getting through   channel.addOrderer(client.newOrderer("orderer.example.com", "grpc://localhost:7050",ordererProperties));

Comment: I am giving  channel.addOrderer(client.newOrderer("orderer.example.com", "grpc://localhost:7050",ordererProperties)); but still its not getting through

Comment: Have the same issue, running on Ubuntu 16.04. Is there any progress to this bug? I will put in edit my sample code.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error. Were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Need to check the Orderer logs if there are any issue there.  You may need to up the timeout. When creating the Orderer add property "ordererWaitTimeMilliSecs" with a value in millisecs "10000" for 10 seconds.

Comment: I added the property and now the same exception started coming after 10 seconds instead of 3, looks like client is not able to reach out to orderer, so not sure which area do I need to debug

Comment: @Girish007 can you please help, as I took most part of code from your one of the example

Comment: Did you look at the orderer log as suggested ? Did it show the transaction id ?
Have you tried all the integration suite against your environment to see if that works ?